# Css of primefaces tab view

Tags: css, primefaces, tabview

I am using the tab view of primefaces. I am facing two issues in it.

1) In IE i am seeing the tabs vertically instead of horizontally. But in firefox it works.

FireFox : 
[image: Firefox]

Internet EXplorer : 
[image: Internet Explorer]

SO which class to override to have tabs in horizontal view.

2) And as you can see the color of unselected tab is different in firefox and IE. I also need to override the style class of unselected tab and selected tab( which i tried to do and i was quite succesful in firefox but in IE .. it doesn't works :(

My code is :

```
    <p:tabView value="#{bean.myDTO}" var="category" id = "tabView" styleClass="TabbedPanelsTabGroup" dynamic="true" onTabChange="handleTabChange(index)">
       <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}" /> 

        <p:tab id = "tab" title = "#{category.category}" titleStyleClass="TabbedPanelsTab TabbedPanelsTabSelected TabbedPanelsContentGroup">

---------Some content------
</p:tab>
</p:tabview>
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Hi, Tarun. You need to show some code or something.

Comment: you give some more clarification for solving your problem. without more clarification anyone cant understand your issue

Comment: I know code is required to understand the problem. but my problem is browser specific and i am using general tags of primefaces and nothing else. I just wannba know how to and and what all properties i need to override to modify CSS. But still i have added code. Please reply .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to correct anything with especific CSS for IE **in this case**.
Just make your page compatible with older IE version adding this to the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I'm adding this using a Servlet Filter, but there are other ways to do this.

And don't forget the !DOCTYPE ...

*...a very old question, but I remember all the headaches I had with this problem some time ago*